# How can I select the 7th <td> element in a list of <tr>'s in Jsoup?

Tags: html, jsoup

[I have a web page full of tr's](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Z2Je.png)

[Every tr has a list of td's that looks like this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gLNuw.png)
Any help is greatly appreciated. What I have done so far is

```
Elements info = document.select("tr").select("td");
```

and it selects all the td's, how do I select the 7th and 8th td?

Comment: Hi new StackOverflow user. Your question would be much easier to read if you'll give us a code as plain code in question instead of images.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.get(index)` to do that. The code below will select the 7th `td` element in the list of `tr`

```
Elements info = document.select("tr td").get(6);
```